# Python code works on Win, not on Linux

Tags: python, linux

I've got a python code to read a data file that runs perfectly fine on Windows. Sorry if this is easy - I'm new to Python.

Now I'm trying to run it on Linux and it won't work. I changed all paths accordingly and the problem seems to be after reading variables in the configuration text file, when it tries to list the file names.

Here's segments of the code and the result:

```
{This is called to read the configuration file at the beginning of the code. It runs and seems to work fine:}
 def readConfig(fn):
 # dynamically create the dictionary from the config file
 # check for duplication  

    config = {}
    file = open(fn,'r')
    lines = file.readlines()
    for x in lines:
#        print x ,re.search("=",x)
        if re.search('=',x) > 0:
#           print x
            parts = x.split("=")
            key = parts[0]
            parts = parts[1].split(" ")
            parts = parts[0].split("\n")
            value = parts[0]
            config[key]=value   #this appends, if key exists it will take 
    print ''
    print config
    print ''
    file.close()
    return config



{Here's where it tries to list the files in the source directory. Source directory src is defined in the configuration file:}
# 5. scan in the src directory and process those files
    src = halo1Config['SRC']
    files = listFiles(src,".hpl")
    print src
    print files



{This is what Listfiles does:}
def listFiles(src,ext):
# get list of files from directory src and subdir below with ext
# ext ="" is okay
    fns=[]
    for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(src, topdown=True):
#    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
        for fname in fileList:
#        print('\t%s' % fname)
            if fname.lower().endswith(ext):
                fn = os.path.join(dirName,fname)
                fns.append(fn)
    return fns
```

In this code, SRC = /home/data/, and inside this folder there are files with names like User1_2015.hpl - these are the data files (text). The code outputs src correctly, but it outputs [] for files, even though there is a long list of files in the src directory. Hence the problem must be with ListFiles, but I can't see what's wrong with it... and it works fine when I use it on Windows!

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You mentioned the problem is reading the configuration file - but you didn't post the code that reads the configuration file. Please edit your question and add the relevant bits.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or, even better, learn [how to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Do the files actually end with `.HPL` on Windows, instead of `.hpl`?

Comment: Sorry, new to stack overflow and python. Just edited code to show how I'm reading the config file. I think it reads the config file fine, since SRC in the config file is correctly printed out later in the code. 

Example: src = /home/data/ and file name in that folder = User1_2015.hpl. Code outputs: src = /home/data , filenames = []

The files end with .hpl (lowercase) on both systems

Comment: In listFiles(), uncomment the two print statements so you can see the directories and files as it reads them.  Also, add an `else:` branch after the `if` with a print statement something like `print('filename %s did not end with extension %s' % (fname.lower(), ext))`.  With that debugging output, I bet you'll see the problem right away.

Comment: They're commented out in this case because the code never gets that far (never reaches those print commands). 
As far as I can tell, the code reaches:  for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(src, topdown=True):
 line and then stops

Comment: If it gets no results from the os.walk() call, then something is amiss.  Do you have permission to read the `/home/data` directory?

Comment: Yup. Permissions aren't an issue.

Comment: Print `src` at the top of `listFiles()`, just as a basic sanity check.  Put quotes around it to make sure there aren't trailing spaces or some such.

Comment: Print src outputs /home/data/{note}
Does anyone know what that means? Maybe it's the problem. By {Note} I mean it looks like a tiny musical note followed immediately after the /. 
The config file only has src = /home/data/ (with no spaces after it) so I'm not sure where this is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import os
fn = os.path.realpath(fn)
```